# boto3 and connecting to custom url

Tags: python, python-2.7, boto3

I have a test environment that mimics the S3 envrionment, and I want to write some test scripts using boto3.  How can I connect to that service?

I tried:

```
 client = boto3.client('s3', region_name="us-east-1", endpoint_url="http://mymachine")
 client = boto3.client('iam', region_name="us-east-1", endpoint_url="http://mymachine")
```

Both fail to work.

The service is setup to use IAM authentication.

My error:

```
 botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Did you set up aws credentials?

Comment: @josh1234 - Is the machine from which your are runnning above boto3 commands is EC2 instance? Or is it normal desktop machine/laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use as below :

```
import boto3 
client = boto3.client( 's3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,)
```

Please check this link for more ways to configure AWS credentials. 
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html

Comment: I cannot use the access_key/secret_key method they setup IAM on the server I am using, which I don't even know is possible to access resources that way.

Comment: If the server you are using is an EC2 instance and it has an IAM role associated with it then you don't have to do anything to find the credentials.  Boto3 will find then for you.

Answer (score -1):

1.
boto API always look for credential to pass on to connecting services, there is no way you can access AWS resources using bot without a access key and password.

If you intended to use some other method, e.g. Temporary Security Credentials, your AWS admin must setup roles and etc , to allow the VM instance connect to AWS using [AWS Security Token Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html).

Otherwise, you must request a restricted credential key from your AWS account admin.

2.On the other hand, if you want to mimics S3 and test rapid upload/download huge amount of data for development, then you should setup [FakeS3](https://github.com/jubos/fake-s3). It will take any dummy access key.  However, there is few drawback of FakeS3 : you can't setup and test S3 bucket policy.

3.Even you configure your S3 bucket to allow anyone to take the file, it is only through the url, it is a file access permission, not bucket access permission.